# Password en/decryption fails with Symfony 3.0

Tags: php, encryption, symfony

Following the documented way to set up user authentication via Doctrine and traditional forms I have ended up in a weird situation: user creation encodes passwords in a different way compared to decoding, so practically my users are unable to log in (Invalid credentials error). However, using some old hash (from an earlier project) and updating the database directly all passwords can be set to 'admin' and they work fine. But this method obviously cannot be maintained for long.

**security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Felhasznalo
                property: username         
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Felhasznalo:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    firewalls:
        default:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: db_provider
            anonymous: true            
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: admin_home
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /login
```

**FelhasznaloController (extends UserController)**

```
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Felhasznalo();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\FelhasznaloType', $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($entity, $entity->getPassword());
        $entity->setPassword($encoded);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_felhasznalo_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
            'felhasznalo' => $entity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

**SecurityController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'admin/security/login.html.twig',
        array(
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}
```

**Felhasznalo.php (User Entity)**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Felhasznalo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="felhasznalo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\FelhasznaloRepository")
 */
class Felhasznalo implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return Felhasznalo
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        // not needed for bcript encoding
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot why the en/decoding fails? At the moment I am only able to login by a migrated user and those where password was set directly in the database to the same password. User creation via a form works beautifully, anyway, except for the generated hash, that is unusable.

Comment: So the problem is only with new users?  You are not somehow storing a salt in the users table?  Does not seem likely based on your posted code but might want to check anyways.